# How to Resolve 'ModuleNotFoundError' When Running Python Script in Azure Runbook?

Tags: python, azure, azure-automation, runbook

I have a python code kept at C drive which uses one Object.py for the below code in the Main.py script

Object.py has below code

```
class FileObject:
    def __init__(self, name, columns, thresholds, uniqueId):
        self.name = str(name).lower()
        self.columns = columns
        self.thresholds = thresholds
        self.uniqueId = uniqueId
```

Main.py has below reference

```
entitiesToProcess = [
    FileObject('csi_fa', ['CorporateName', 'TaxVatNumber','Full_Address'], [0.95, 0.95, 0.90], 'UIDFac')
    ]
```

Which works fine when I execute location through cmd.
I have uploaded the Main.py script to azure runbook and now getting error
I am directly using in runbook

```
class FileObject:
    def __init__(self, name, columns, thresholds, uniqueId):
        self.name = str(name).lower()
        self.columns = columns
        self.thresholds = thresholds
        self.uniqueId = uniqueId


entitiesToProcess = [
    FileObject('csi_fa', ['CorporateName', 'TaxVatNumber', 'Full_Address'], [0.95, 0.95, 0.90], 'UIDFac')
]
```

```
error : - line 7, in <module>    from Object import FileObjectModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Object'
```

how do i solve

Answer (score 0):

*I also received the same error when I tried in my environment firstly.*

[image]

***To resolve this,***

Before importing the module, add the path of the directory containing the `Object.py` file to the `sys.path` list in runbook using `sys.path.append()`.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\<path>\Object.py')
from Object import FileObject
```

*After adding this to the code, it worked as expected.*

[image]

Refer this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for the module search path.